# Apple Wish Tk.framework always returns 137 with invalid code signature

Tags: crash

I have the problem that I am trying to get started with an application that is based on the Tk framework. Unfortunately wish always returns permission denied when called directly and when calling it with the program it says `"/usr/bin/wish: line 2:  1326 Killed: 9 "$(dirname $0)/../../System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Resources/Wish.app/Contents/MacOS/Wish" "$@""`.

When I go to the directory and click on the icon of Wish.app it opens without a problem.

Path to the system app `/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Resources/Wish.app/Contents/MacOS`